# Active directory user account images not syncing with SharePoint User Profiles

Tags: 2013, user-profile, user-profile-service, user-profile-property, profile-sync

I am uploading the images in Active Directory and trying to sync them with User Profile Services (tried both Incremental and Full Synchronization) but still not able to retrieve the AD User Profile Image.

Any help would be appreciated here.

Answer (score 1):

Is your user profile property "Picture" mapped to the correct AD attribute- "thumbnailPhoto" ? Also, the user profile photos from AD are stored in sharepoint picture library in Mysite host site collection. you need to run the powershell command

```
Update-SPProfilePhotoStore -CreateThumbnailsForImportedPhotos 1 -MySiteHostLocation %MySiteURL%
```

[Here](http://richardstk.com/2013/04/12/import-user-photos-from-active-directory-into-sharepoint-2013/) is a reference link

Comment: yes AD profile property mapped. I will try the above way out.

Comment: is there any restriction on image size and image (png/jpg)?

Answer (score 1):

To import Profile picture into Sharepoint, you need to perform 3 things.

1. Map the picture attribute to ThumanailPhoto.
2. Run the Full Sync
3. Now run the createThumbnail command to create the thumbnail.

You can verify at this link `http://oursite/mysites/User Photos/Profile Pictures` if pictures imported.

here is the link: http://sharepointadam.com/2010/11/18/import-user-profile-photos-from-active-directory-into-sharepoint-2010/

Comment: why is there need for Full Sync, can't we get it using Incremental?

Comment: whenever you create new mapping to a property or Change the property...then full sync required to properly update the data. Yes you can't get the result with incremental.

Comment: read the  Perform full or incremental crawl headings...http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd819091(v=office.12).aspx#BKMK_Performafullorincrementalcrawl

Comment: thats good. but if i update email, name or any other user property value in profile would that be updated with Incremental Sync

Comment: that's the values for user, but when you change the property mapping i.e picture property to mapp the thumbnailPhoto..this is required full...But if user change the Pictures in AD then it will picked in incremental crawl.

Comment: is there any restriction on image size and image (png/jpg)?