# User profile synchronisation service doesn't have export direction for Picture

Tags: user-profile-property

I have provisioned User Profile Synchronisation Service Application and configured it to use Active Directory Import. I've done a full synchronisation and i have all my users in User Profiles.

I am now trying to allow user to update their own profile images by adding a mapping to the Picture.

I'm following this [guide](http://blogs.technet.com/b/nishants/archive/2012/02/21/how-to-sync-picture-from-sharepoint-to-active-directory-and-hence-to-outlook-and-lync.aspx), but under the "Add New Mapping > Direction" there's no export.

[image]

How do you enable?

Comment: refer the link : http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/115468/active-directory-user-account-images-not-syncing-with-sharepoint-user-profiles

Comment: Does it work for export? I can already choose import currently

Comment: which sharepoint version are you using. its enabled at my end.

Comment: im using sp 2013..

Comment: try executing the User Profile Service timer job once and see the changes if anything reflects

Comment: I've done a full crawl, but there's still no export option in the mapping..

Comment: are you able to see any available properties under "Manage User Properties" section

Comment: Yes i am able to see "Pictures", but under the add new mapping i can only select import for the direction, there's no export..

Answer (score 1):

1) Please verify whether "User Profile Service Application" -> "Configure Synchronization Connections" are configured properly and all the AD User properties are crawled after full crawl.

2) You would see the properties in "User Profile Service Application" -> "Manage User Properties as below"
[image]

3) Once this works fine you can add new property mapping as below :
[image]

I think there is some problem in crawling at your end. Kindly create a new synchronization connection and follow the steps, it should work.

Comment: Which one are you using? Use SharePoint Profile Synchronization or Use SharePoint Active Directory Import

Comment: I had used SharePoint Profile Synchronization.

Comment: Is it possible to do export using SharePoint AD Import?

Answer (score 0):

The *Export* direction is not available when you use the Active Directory Import mode (the only one available in SP2016 by default), only if you use FIM (for SP2013).

See : https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/administration/configure-profile-synchronization-by-using-sharepoint-active-directory-import#situations-unsupported-by-ad-import